# Deployment scenario: Way to swap COM DLLs having different bitness - ASP.NET Website, dev 64 vs prod 32

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web, 64-bit, 32-bit

We're developing an ASP.NET Website on a 64-bit machine with VS 2008, and deploying it to a 32-bit Windows staging server.

We have two versions of a COM DLL in our posession:

- Assembly32.dll for 32 bit machines
- Assembly64.dll for 64 bit machines

We know what to use where.

The question is **how do we make an easy deployment scenario** out of this situation? We'd rather not have a manual process in place to change the DLL on the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not be sneaky and just switch the dev machines to 32-bit IIS?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435